Facebook Login for Business: "It looks like this app isn't available" error
My app is working well, as long as I only use the account that "owns" the app with Facebook Login. As soon as I try to log in with a different facebook account, I get the "It looks like this app isn't available" error.
I have a set of permissions:
email
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_posts
pages_show_list
pages_manage_metadata

I was set up with Facebook Login for Business (why? no idea). But I set up a configuration with the "General" login variation, user access token, and that same set of permissions (where is public profile? It's not in the list).
My call to FB.login:
FB.login( function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        statusChangeCallback(response, true);
    }
}, {
    config_id: "<CONFIG ID>",
    response_type: 'code',
});

I have tried with and without the "response_type" value, and with and without the "override_default_response_type" value. What am I doing wrong here? I wanted to try to delete the Facebook Login for Business product and add the basic Facebook Login product, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do the former, and the latter isn't  in the set of available products. And despite this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/

There doesn't seem to be a way to roll back to Facebook Login.

Facing the same issue Andy. Did you manage to resolve the problem? Did you fully verify your business and still facing this problem?

Yes, our business has been verified (which was a total PIA). It MIGHT be that our app hasn't been verified (though they let me make it live). So I'm going through that process now, with completely mystifying responses from the verification team. Arg.
